# Combining multiple ef6 linq queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm having an issue with combining multiple ef6 linq queries

Here the code works when the two linq queries are separated

```
 List<int> skipRoomIds = hbContext.Reservations.Include(x => x.Room)
                           .Where(x => (x.FromDate < fromDate && fromDate < x.ToDate) || (x.FromDate < toDate && toDate < x.ToDate) ||
                           (fromDate < x.FromDate && x.FromDate < toDate) || (fromDate < x.ToDate && x.ToDate < toDate))
                           .Select(x => x.Room.Id).ToList(); //First query

                       roomRows = hbContext.Rooms.Where(x => !skipRoomIds.Contains(x.Id) && x.MaxNumOfPeople >= numOfPeople)
                           .Select(x=> new RoomRow() { From = fromDate, To = toDate, Room = x}).ToList(); //Second query
```

But when I try and combine the two I get an error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[HotelBooker.Models.Reservation] Include[Reservation,Room](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[HotelBooker.Models.Reservation], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[HotelBooker.Models.Reservation,HotelBooker.Models.Room]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
```

In the first linq query I get a list of integers to then use to check something in the where part of the second linq query, but then when I put the first linq query inside the second one it doesn't work.

Why would I want that ? well so I don't send more requests to the sql server then necessary.

```
roomRows = hbContext.Rooms.Where(z => !hbContext.Reservations.Include(x => x.Room)
                           .Where(x => (x.FromDate < fromDate && fromDate < x.ToDate) || (x.FromDate < toDate && toDate < x.ToDate) ||
                           (fromDate < x.FromDate && x.FromDate < toDate) || (fromDate < x.ToDate && x.ToDate < toDate))
                           .Select(x => x.Room.Id).AsEnumerable().Contains(z.Id)
                    && z.MaxNumOfPeople >= numOfPeople)
                          .Select(z => new RoomRow() { From = fromDate, To = toDate, Room = z }).ToList();
```

Can anybody explain why combining multiple linq queries doesn't work with ef6 or if I'm doing it wrong ? and how would you do select statements in where or select part of an sql statement in linq ef6 ?

Sql statement example:

select * from table where id in (select id in table2);

I have tried searching for the answer but couldn't find anything, perhaps I had the wrong keywords when searching the problem.

Comment: _"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method..."_ Please include the full error content. It will tell you which method it's failing to recognise

Comment: The error is complaining about the use of the `Include` method. This is not something that can be converted to SQL and prompts the error you're seeing. You cannot next your queries like this! I'm not sure you really need the `Include` as it only prompts EF to populate those properties in your results and not act as part of the filter

Comment: @phuzi wow ! I removed it and it works now.... well from what I learned it has to do with lazy & eager loading. I only want to load the room and not the other properties is there another way to go about it ?

Comment: _" I only want to load the room and not the other properties is there another way to go about it"_ I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. Perhaps it should be another question on SO.

Comment: `Include` is ignored anyway when a query contains a projection (`Select(x => x.Room.Id)`). It's a common misconception that you need `Include` to be able to access a navigation property later in the query.